# About the JOIN keyword

Tags: sql, join

Here is my question I have this `SQL` Query:

```
SELECT * FROM leftTable
JOIN rightTable
ON leftTable.match = rightTable.match
```

is `JOIN` a left join, a right join or an inner Join?

Comment: sql server? oracle? mysql? other?

Comment: It is an inner join operation. "JOIN" is just short for "INNER JOIN".

Comment: Always specify which join you mean for clarity of code and no ambiguities.  Never use just "JOIN".  That's just good practice.

Comment: @pmbAustin There is no ambiguity. `a JOIN b` is always `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You are talking about the DEFAULT join. A NATURAL join is something else

Comment: Then always write "INNER JOIN" if that's what you mean.  Never use just plain "JOIN"... always make it clear:  INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, or CROSS JOIN.  That's easy and obvious "best practice".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN`.

`LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` and `FULL JOIN` are technically short for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` respectively. Standard compliant SQL parsers aren't required to accept the long versions.

Comment: ok in this case the the order of the table is important in the request. for example if we want the match on the left table with the short form of the INNER JOIN we should put it first. right?!

Comment: I'm not sure what "short form" means but order of the tables is not important in INNER JOIN. They do affect the order of the columns in the "select *" however.

Comment: and what is the short form of FULL OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` keyword used alone refers to `INNER JOIN`, otherwhise you have to explecity define which join you want to use e.g

```
LEFT JOIN
FULL JOIN
e.t.c
```

Comment: Correct ,Full i meant...typo fixed

Answer (score -5):

in MySQL it's a join. I would recommend you to avoid using "*" and just retrieve the fields that you are going to use (MySQL eng could handle faster with it).

```
<http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html>
```

Comment: A join is a join...this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Take a look in the link that I posted. It has all information about natural join. You can check that the natural join is a join.

Comment: Then you should explicitly put that into your answer; when your answer to "Is JOIN a LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN or INNER JOIN" is "in MySQL it's a join", something's not being communicated clearly.